# algorithm - find the position of item in the queue

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have an array of arbitrary objects

1. Each object has a unique id
2. New objects are added at the end of the queue (tail)
3. Objects are removed from the top for the processing (FIFO)
4. Objects pending processing can be deleted if requires.

Problem is to find the Object current position in the queue from the tail given the id.

What is the quickest way to do it? Just to be clear, I do not want Object from the id so just the hash map is not the solution. What I really need is the position.

We thought of two ways:

1. Brute-force, find in a loop
2. add a new field in Object which stores a global index that is incremented for every object added to the queue. We can then quickly get the position by checking the global index stored in the last item and this item. However, the only complexity is that if one of the objects is deleted, the global index of all the items below needs to be updated.

Any better ideas? Please suggest.

Comment: Do you consider an option to have amortized time complexity? Briefly, we will use shallow delete from the array (not real, just mark that this object should be deleted). Then when we have the situation that more than 30% of the capacity occupied by the marked objects, we process recalc.

Comment: Maybe #2 but maintain the global indexes in a run-length encoded form, i.e. global id and number of consecutive id values. You can find your id quickly adding up the runs you skip over and then calculating the final offset. To delete you split a run-length into two, or shorten it, or remove it as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have an `log(n)` time solution. Construct a hash table that maps each `ID` to its node in our other data structure- a self-balancing binary search tree (red-black, AVL, whatever you like). In this tree, a node should be ordered by its relative priority / order in your queue. It should also store a pointer to its parent in the tree, and the size of the subtree rooted at itself. From this we can query for the number of elements with a lower priority / order in logarithmic time.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to represent the FIFO as a doubly-linked list. This list can either be of `Object`s  (meaning that if you had an ID you would also need a mapping, either a hash map or some other approach, from ID to object), or of standalone FIFO nodes (in which case you'd have a mapping from ID to node address).